# Why won't my default class import in ES6?

Tags: ecmascript-6, webpack, babeljs

I'm working with babel-loader inside webpack for the first time, and I'm very new to ES6 as well.  I'm trying to export a base class from one file and import it into another.  Exporting and importing has worked fine throughout my file thus far, and I am just now hitting a problem with it for the first time while trying to create classes.

Here's what my code looks like:

**BaseClient.js**

```
export default class BaseClient {
  // snip...
};
```

**SessionClient.js**

```
import BaseClient from './BaseClient';

// outputs "undefined":
console.log(BaseClient);

// throws "Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined":
export default class SessionClient extends BaseClient {
  // snip...
};
```

Am I doing something wrong?  Is there any relevant information I'm missing from my question that's needed before diagnosing?  Thanks!

Comment: That should work iirc. Are you using the right path?

Comment: I am using the right path.  I tried a fake path to make sure, and it gave me an error about the file not existing, so I know it's correct.

Comment: Is this a simplified example? Just wondering if you might have any circular references in your actual code, as that could lead to this issue.

Comment: Yep, that was it.  I figured it out late last night that I accidentally created a circular reference when splitting out the base client.  Add your comment as an answer, and I'll accept it. :)

Comment: Same issue on a totally different code. It was also a circular dependency issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, I met the issue as well. It's caused by circular reference between different files in very long reference chain.
Like following:
[image]